# Redirect push notification to native app

Tags: android, ios, mobile, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Is there a way to redirect a remote push notification to a local native app when the users taps the notification? For example, a new email arrives on our server, we send push notification to client, they tap notification, it opens native app instead of our app?

If so, is this possible on both iOS and Android?

Comment: Do you mean you want to use a system app to handle your tailor made push notification instead of your own app. If yes, it's not possible in iOS. In iOS, a tailor made push notification can only be sent to your own tailor made app that is registered to receive that notification. It in turn can off course open a system app like mail.

Comment: Do you know if it can use the system mail app to reply to a mail message? I think I've noticed on iOS I can share via email and it popups up a compose window, from within the app, not the native app. Interesting. Not sure if this is possible on android.

Comment: In iOS you have `MFMailComposeViewController` inside `MessageUI.framework` that lets you programmatically open up the system mail composer from within your app. Not sure if you are talking about this.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible on Android, but you have to rig it yourself.

You just need to know which package name to target for the notification, and when you receive the notification, use a pending intent to launch that package.

you can either have them hard coded in the app and have some way of id'ing the notification to figure out which package name to launch, or you can package the package name in the payload of the notification.